# Join two columns in SSRS 2016 space between the words of the new field

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, service, reporting

I have merged/joined two columns adding a new field in my data-set using the following code/expression `=Fields!Officer.Value+Fields!offLastName.Value` it gave me the outcome i wanted but the space between the two words is a lot and I can't get the new field to look right in my report. I need to reduce the space between the two words please help.

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try `RTRIM` on the `Officer` and/or `LTRIM` on the `offLastName`.

Comment: try =Fields!Officer.Value+trim(Fields!offLastName.Value)

Comment: i got it work  like this =rtrim(Fields!Officer.Value)+" "+Fields!offLastName.Value thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is tagged "sql" and "sql-server" suggesting that the data is coming from a database.

If so, you can use database functions to remove leading and trailing spaces and do the concatenation in the database.

The SQL would look something like this:

```
select ltrim(rtrim(FirstName)) + ' ' + ltrim(rtrim(LastName))
```

Comment: i got it work like this =rtrim(Fields!Officer.Value)+" "+Fields!offLastName.Value thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
=rtrim(Fields!Officer.Value)+" "+Fields!offLastName.Value
```